# Javascript Column Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck in a bit of a situation here and it would be great if someone could help me. Recently I created a package page for a client and included a JS hover effect so that I could hover over elements all together using different columns in Bootstrap. Now this is probably simple, but where I am stuck is the short space between columns, I am giving an example image ..

[image]

The JS:

```
var classes = ["el1", "el2", "el3", "el4", "el5", "el6", "el7", "el8", "el9","el10","el11","el12", "el13","el14","el15","el16","el17","el18","el19","el20","el21","el22", "el23", "el24","el25" ]; //list of your classes
var elms = {};
var n = {}, nclasses = classes.length;
function changeColor(classname, color) {
    var curN = n[classname];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[classname][i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var k = 0; k < nclasses; k ++) {
    var curClass = classes[k];
    elms[curClass] = document.getElementsByClassName(curClass);
    n[curClass] = elms[curClass].length;
    var curN = n[curClass];
    for(var i = 0; i < curN; i ++) {
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseover = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "#dbdbdb");
        };
        elms[curClass][i].onmouseout = function() {
            changeColor(this.className, "transparent");
        };
    }
};
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="packagecontent" class="container-fluid" style="display: block;">
<div class="row">
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" id="pkg-main-col">
    <div class="row pkg-inner">
    <div class="header-image wp-image-404 size-full" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="pkg-pricing">
        <h5>PRICING</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el1">Monthly Pricing (Billed Annually)</li>
            <li class="el2">Monthly Pricing (Billed Monthly)</li>
            <li class="el3">Products</li>
            <li class="el4">Competitors</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-competitor-comparison">
        <h5>COMPETIROR COMPARISON</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el5">Products*</li>
            <li class="el6">Prices*</li>
            <li class="el7">Attributes*</li>
            <li class="el8">Images*</li>
            <li class="el9">Related Products*</li>
            <li class="el10">Videos*</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-post-comparison-processing">
        <h5>POST-COMPARISON PROCESSING</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el11">Attributes*</li>
            <li class="el12">Images*</li>
            <li class="el13">Related Videos*</li>
            <li class="el14">Videos*</li>
            <li class="el15">Reviews*</li>
            <li class="el16">SEO Friendly product descriptions*</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-support">
        <h5>SUPPORT</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el17">Full Knowledge base*</li>
            <li class="el18">Launch guidance*</li>
            <li class="el19" >Email Support*</li>
            <li class="el20">Phone Support*</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-compatibility">
        <h5>COMPATIBILITY</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el21">Support all e-commerce software*</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-reporting">
        <h5>REPORTING</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el22">User Friendly Dashboard*</li>
            <li class="el23">Import-Export Tool*</li>
            <li class="el24">Easy to print reports*</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-access-security">
        <h5>Security and access</h5>
        <ul class="package-cat" style="text-align:left;">
            <li class="el25">SSL Encription*</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" id="pkg-col">
    <div class="row pkg-inner">

    <div class="header-image wp-image-404 size-full"> <p>FREE</p></div>
    <div class="pkg-pricing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el1">&pound; 0 / month</li>
            <li class="el2">&pound; 0 / month</li>
            <li class="el3">10</li>
            <li class="el4">1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-competitor-comparison col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el5"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el6"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el7"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el8"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el9"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el10"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-post-comparison-processing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el11"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el12"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el13"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el14"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el15"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el16"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-support col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el17"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el18"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el19">24/7</li>
            <li class="el20"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-compatibility col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el21"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-reporting col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el22"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el23"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el24"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-access-security col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat">
            <li class="el25"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" id="pkg-col">
    <div class="row pkg-inner">
    <div class="header-image wp-image-404 size-full"><p>BASIC</p></div>
    <div class="pkg-pricing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el1">&pound; 25 / month</li>
            <li class="el2">&pound; 29 / month</li>
            <li class="el3">50</li>
            <li class="el4">1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-competitor-comparison col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat " style="list-style-type: none;display:block;">
            <li class="el5"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el6"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el7"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el8"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el9"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el10"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-post-comparison-processing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el11"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el12"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el13"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el14"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el15"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el16"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-support col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el17"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el18"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el19">24/7</li>
            <li class="el20"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-compatibility col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el21"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-reporting col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el22"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el23"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el24"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-access-security col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el25"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" id="pkg-col" >
    <div class="row pkg-inner">
    <div class="header-image wp-image-404 size-full"><p>PROFESSIONAL</p></div>
    <div class="pkg-pricing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el1">&pound; 99 / month</li>
            <li class="el2">&pound; 109 / month</li>
            <li class="el3">unlimited</li>
            <li class="el4">unlimited</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-competitor-comparison col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat " style="list-style-type: none;display:block;">
            <li class="el5"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el6"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el7"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el8"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el9"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el10"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-post-comparison-processing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el11"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el12"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el13"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el14"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el15"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el16"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-support col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el17"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el18"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el19">24/7</li>
            <li class="el20"><i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility: hidden;;color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-compatibility col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el21"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-reporting col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el22"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el23"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el24"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-access-security col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el25"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" id="pkg-col">
    <div class="row pkg-inner">

    <div class="header-image wp-image-404 size-full"><p>ENTERPRISE</p></div>
    <div class="pkg-pricing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el1">&pound; 249 / month</li>
            <li class="el2">&pound; 269 / month</li>
            <li class="el3">unlimited</li>
            <li class="el4">unlimited</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-competitor-comparison col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el5"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el6"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el7"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el8"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el9"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el10"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-post-comparison-processing col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el11"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el12"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el13"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el14"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el15"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el16"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-support col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el17"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el18"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el19">24/7</li>
            <li class="el20">8/5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-compatibility col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el21"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-reporting col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el22"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el23"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
            <li class="el24"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pkg-access-security col-data">
        <ul class="package-cat" style="list-style-type: none;display:block;text-align:center;">
            <li class="el25"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put this into codepen or js fiddle? if i understand what you're after, you shouldn't need javascript to accomplish this.

Comment: So you want the hover effect to appear on the gaps too?

Comment: Are you hovering and highlighting the "row" ... you keep mentioning column, but then the short gap would not be an issue.  The gap I see is between the bootstrap columns.  Basically, you will need to modify the CSS to eliminate the gap between (it should be a margin-left, margin-right issue).

Comment: lol. again, @fahad-sohail... We probably wont be of much help until you can put your code into a pen or something. Definitely glad to help, if so.

Comment: Sorry for late reply mates. Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/dffn1L4u/1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use CSS to do this:

```
el1.hover{ ... }
```

to specify what happens ONLY during hover.
Now, heres how you do it:

**Method 1: Creating a new div in CSS**

Create a division for every row within the `<ul class='package-cat'>`.

```
<div class="selectBox"/>
```

Then, in CSS, set the default state to hidden, and set the height OR width respectively:

```
.selectBox{
  visibility: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: COLOR_WHEN_HOVERING;
}
```

And then add a hover in CSS that changes visibility to visible.

```
.selectBox:hover{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Tada!

EDIT: Make sure the coloring div is created before the text, so that it doesn't cover it up.

**Method 2: Replacing Margins/Padding with divs and add class**

This one is simple - remove all margins on the left and right of the other divs, and replace them with new divs made solely to provide the colored margin between each original div.

```
<div class="marginDiv"/>
```

CSS:

```
.marginDiv{background-color: COLOR_WHEN_NOT_HOVERING; width: SPACING;}
.marginDiv:hover{background-color: COLOR_WHEN_HOVERING}
```

Hooray!

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. I have gone through a lot to make this responsive, messing with the margins is the last thing I want to do. Can you please implement your Method 1 on the first segment in here JSfiddle ( jsfiddle.net/dffn1L4u/1 ), so I get an idea of your method? I'll be really thankful ..

Comment: Hey Fahad! Sorry for taking so long to reply. I found an easier way to do it, will be posting the fiddle soon

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dffn1L4u/4/
The new method involves making absolute divs and making their width ridiculously high. But I can't figure out how to get the text to go above the div.
As for the original method, I did not look at your code correctly and it turns out that you are using the standard vertical tables - which is not compatible. Really sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I really appreciate your efforts towards solving this issue, but I think I just solved it. The issue was that I was using borders between the columns and that was breaking it into parts, now its fixed. Thank you again for your help and efforts ..

Comment: Glad to see that it was solved. Sorry I couldn't have been of any help.